Почему теряется соединение с базой данных во flask?
Я делаю сайт на flask и столкнулся с проблемой, спустя 10-15 минут сайт теряет соединение с бд и зависает, а спустя минуту выводит в консоль ошибку о потере соединения, помогает только перезагрузка. Пробовал использовать connect_timeout=86400 но без результата
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')

С чем это связано?

А вы что - держите один и тот же коннекшен? Это же не модно уже лет много как. Нужно на каждое действие заново коннекшен открывать и потом закрывать. У базы есть пул конекшенов, они быстро нынче открываются.

А вообще вот в документации есть специальный раздел: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/error-lost-connection.html

@CrazyElf У БД не может быть пула открытых коннектов с клиентом. Если питон открывает соединение то ему все равно надо установить tcp соединение, а это обмен минимум 5 пакетами. запросто в 10ms может выйти. Вообще модно держать пул соединений со стороны питона.

А у вас автокоммит на соединениях стоит или если нет, то не забываете ли вы дать commit() в конце любой операции, если вы даже делали просто select ? меня "during query" в сообщении об ошибке напрягает, как будто во время долгого таймаута какая то транзакция еще шла, а это большая проблема, даже если бы соединение не рвалось

@Mike, ошибка появляется во время запроса

И при этом "минуту висит", может сам запрос медленно слишком выполняется. Там у Mysql вполне могут быть настройки отдельные для вермени выполнения запроса. Но вообще тогда надо взять запрос и попробовать не flask. И если медленный - то оптимизировать его

@Mike при чем тут медленный запрос? Когда сайт только запустился все нормально, а кода стоит то уже появляются проблемы

тогда возвращаемся к предыдущему вопросу про транзакции. Если он падает при попытке выполнить запрос после простоя, в самом начале выполнения, то вопрос в том в каком состоянии было соединение перед простоем, с открытой транзакцией или нет

@Mike то есть без conn.close()?

Без commit() (если не включен автокоммит при соединении). Кстати я тут доку открыл по MySQL. connect_timeout про который вы написали это таймаут во время установления соединения и первичного обмена пакетами. Смотрите interactive_timeout и wait_timeout, хотя они большие по умолчанию. net_read_timeout (если вы вдруг не дочитали данные перед ожиданием), А еще, вы пул у себя используете или голое соединение один раз при старте как от открываете ?

Пулы не использую, а обязательно использовать commit если идет SELECT?

select блочит записи, там хоть и легкая блокировка, но она есть. И ее долго держать не хорошо. Поэтому я обычно все соединения держу с autocommit=True, а транзакции начинаю только тогда, когда они мне действительно нужны

ало у меня только SELECT в коде, какой смысл вообще от autocommit???

Потому что если его нет, то после вашего select транзакция все равно считается открытой, и вас вполне могут отключить по истечении времени простоя в транзакции

@Mike ваш autocommit не помог
